# Split DataFrame CSV file using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, signal-processing, export-to-csv

I appended a list into data frame using Python then saved it as CSV file, I tried to separate the generated list into separated cells in excel but no success, Here is a picture of the CSV file :
[Sample of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taNrd.png)

As shown, the "value" column contains all the numbers in one cell, I thought that it might work using slicing but it isn't, example of code that it is not working:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'data/pre_processed/test2.csv') 
df2 = df1.iloc[:, [1[0]]].copy() 
df2
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-82923653224e> in <module>
      1 df1 = pd.read_csv(r'data/pre_processed/test2.csv')
----> 2 df2 = df1.iloc[:, [1[0]]].copy()
      3 df2

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there a way to have this type of CSV file so that I can use it for data training?
[Sample of wanted CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5flEA.jpg)

I have used this code to append the data frame:

```
try:
    wav_file_name = row['wav_file']
    label = labels[row['label']]
    y = audio_vectors[wav_file_name]
    split_test = []
    length=len(y)
    start, stop = 0, 512
     while stop <= length:
            f0 = y[start:stop]
            split_test.append(f0)
            f1=np.transpose(f0)
            split_test.append(f1)
            start, stop = stop, stop + 512 
            split_list = [label,f1]   
            
                df_split = df_split.append(pd.DataFrame(split_list, index=columns1).transpose(), ignore_index=True)
            except:
                print('Some exception occured')

df_split.to_csv('data/pre_processed/test2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried iterating through each array to provide values in each column?

Comment: Can you please show how you made the data frame in the first place?

Comment: @jros I used while loop to append the values into list: df_test = df_test.append(pd.DataFrame(test2, index=columns1).transpose(), ignore_index=True)

Comment: @pedrosaurio I have added that part